# Save data to CSV file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add some data which I get from user using html form to CSV file in ruby on rails. How can I do this? Here is my code for this

```
<p>
<h2>Register using form below</h2>
<p class="error"></p>
<form action="" method="post" class="scrum-form">
<p><h3>Participant information</h3></p>
<div>
<label>Full name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="full_name" class="full_name" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Email<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="email" class="email" />
</div>
<div>    
<label>Phone number<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="phone" class="phone" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Organization name<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="organization" class="organization" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Job title<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="job" class="job" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Special diet<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="diet" class="diet" />
</div>
<p><h3>Billing information</h3></p>
<div>
<label>Address<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="address" name="address" class="address"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<label>Postal code<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="code" class="code" />
</div>
<div>
<label>City<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="city" class="city" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Cost pool or reference<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="cost_pool" class="cost_pool" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="button" name="register" value="Register" onclick="registration();" />
</div>
</form>
</p>
```

here is my action code

```
full_name = params["full_name"]
email = params["email"]
phone = params["phone"]
organization = params["organization"]
job = params["job"]
diet = params["diet"]
address = params["address"]
code = params["code"]
city = params["city"]
cost_pool = params["cost_pool"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at rubies CSV library (aka FasterCSV) http://apidock.com/ruby/CSV

or watch one of the latest railscasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Comment: I followed your first link and now data is added to csv file. but now every time when I add some data using that form it adds on the same line so it removes the previously saved data and insert new one in that place. But I want to add new information in the next line. How can I do this?

Comment: Use `'a'` instead of `'w'` when opening the file.

Answer (score 6):

I will give you an example:

```
@file = "example.csv"

CSV.open(@file, "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["data"]
  csv << ["data2", "data3"]
end
```

Here we have a `csv` file and we open it with `CSV.open`. We have to add inside the `csv` always `arrays` with some data. Each time we call `csv << array` will be a new line inside the `csv` file. Also, the elements inside the `array` will be separated by commas inside the file.

So, returning to the example, or `"example.csv"` file will have `"data"` on it's first line, and `"data2,data3"` on it's second line.

Check the links @phoet posted on his answer. Will help you understand the example and anything else you may need.

**EDITED**

You can solve your comments problem by changing the `"wb"` inside `CSV.open` call.

If you pass `"ab"` instead I belive it will solve your problem, like this:

```
   CSV.open(@file, "ab") do |csv|
      csv << ["your_new_next_line_data"]
    end
```

Anyway, here is a link with all the options you can pass: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html.

Comment: I followed your code and now data is added to csv file. but now every time when I add some data using that form it adds on the same line so it removes the previously saved data and insert new one in that place. But I want to add new information in the next line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Writing to csv files is straightforward with the built-in CSV class in ruby: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Instead of coupling your controller to this file, however, I'd recommend the approach of sticking to the rails paradigm of updating your model (and using a standard database) when the form is filled out. Then, you can have rake tasks or admin pages that can export the data you want from your database into csv. Many people really like [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) for this kind of functionality.